# Is it bad practice to make an UI element singleton?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, user-interface, cocos2d-iphone

Particularly in `iOS` and `Cocos2d`. What if i need a lot of classes to interact with say `CCScene` or `UIView` which is only one in my application?  Is it normal to make it shared, an ordinary singleton? What are pros (if they are there) and cons of such an approach?

Comment: Using a singleton for UI component won't be work.. Because `UIView` will have only one `superView`. So when you place it in another place, then old position will be gone.. You can make a subclass of it and make a generic component and use it wherever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few cons:

- you won't be able to create new instances of your element - for example if you want to create a new view or scene and replace the old one
- you have to consider instantiation from different threads
- if you change a method's signature, you'll have to update many classes

I think it's better to implement the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern if the element is view or a wrapper for other type of element and make all your classes use this controller/wrapper.